# How do I check if a directory is writeable in PHP?

Tags: php, permissions, directory

Does anyone know how I can check to see if a directory is writeable in PHP?

The function [`is_writable`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) doesn't work for folders.

> Edit: It does work. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Yes, it does work for folders....

> Returns TRUE if the filename  exists and is writable. The filename argument may be a directory name allowing you to check if a directory is writable.

Comment: The trick is that you can't specify a *file* that doesn't exist yet within the folder you really want to test - just specify the folder.

Answer (score 26):

this is the code :)

```
<?php 

$newFileName = '/var/www/your/file.txt';

if ( ! is_writable(dirname($newFileName))) {

    echo dirname($newFileName) . ' must writable!!!';
} else {

    // blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: Ahh, `dirname($new_file_name)`, that's simpler than what I was going to do. I was going to use `pathinfo($new_file_name,PATHINFO_DIRNAME)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

to be more specific for owner/group/world

```
$dir_writable = substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($folder)), -4) == "0774" ? "true" : "false";
```

peace...

Comment: This function should be improved. Right now it would return false for permissions like `0777`.

Answer (score 5):

You may be sending a complete file path to the `is_writable()` function. `is_writable()` will return false if the file doesn't already exist in the directory. You need to check the directory itself with the filename removed, if this is the case. If you do that, `is_writable` will correctly tell you whether the directory is writable or not. If `$file` contains your file path do this:

```
$file_directory = dirname($file);
```

Then use `is_writable($file_directory)` to determine if the folder is writable.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation for is_writable](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php), it should just work - but you said "folder", so this could be [a Windows issue](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27609). The comments suggest [a workaround](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php#68098).

(A rushed reading earlier made me think that trailing slashes were important, but that turned out to be specific to this work around).

Answer (score 4):

I've written a little script (I call it *isWritable.php*) that detects all directories in the same directory the script is in and writes to the page whether each directory is writable or not. Hope this helps.

```
<?php
// isWritable.php detects all directories in the same directory the script is in
// and writes to the page whether each directory is writable or not.

$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');

foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
    if (is_writable($dir)) {
        echo $dir.' is writable.<br>';
    } else {
        echo $dir.' is not writable. Permissions may have to be adjusted.<br>';
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: you can use $dirs = glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

Answer (score 2):

stat()

Much like a system stat, but in PHP.  What you want to check is the mode value, much like you would out of any other call to stat in other languages (I.E. C/C++).

https://www.php.net/stat

Answer (score 1):

According to the PHP manual [is_writable](http://de3.php.net/is-writable) should work fine on directories.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `is_writable` returned true, but when tried to write the file - an error was generated.
This code helps to check if the `$dir` exists and is writable:

```
<?php
$dir = '/path/to/the/dir';

// try to create this directory if it doesn't exist
$booExists     = is_dir($dir) || (mkdir($dir, 0774, true) && is_dir($dir));
$booIsWritable = false;
if ($booExists && is_writable($dir)) {
    $tempFile = tempnam($dir, 'tmp');
    if ($tempFile !== false) {
        $res = file_put_contents($tempFile, 'test');

        $booIsWritable = $res !== false;
        @unlink($tempFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I do it:

create a file with `file_put_contents()` and check the return value, if it is positive (number of written in Bytes) then you can go ahead and do what you have to do, if it is FALSE then it is not writable

```
$is_writable = file_put_contents('directory/dummy.txt', "hello");

if ($is_writable > 0) echo "yes directory it is writable";

else echo  "NO directory it is not writable";
```

then you can delete the dummy file by using unlink()

```
unlink('directory/dummy.txt');
```

Comment: While this technically works, it is definitely not the recommended method. Filesystem operations are relatively slow and incur a lot of overhead, so creating a dummy file and then deleting/unlinking it is **much** slower than most other methods.