# Trying to copy a local PHP page, creating a directory (if needed), place copy in directory, and rename

Tags: php, html, copying

I have tried everything i can to get a php page to copy itself when it loads, create a directory if its not there already, and then place itself in said directory renamed. I have been googling for almost 2 days now with lots of close results but nothing clear. Im still a newbie with PHP so i could use a little help here for a push in the right direction. I have no database what so ever by the way.

This is the order in how my site works currently.

### Search → (No Result ↓)(Result →) Success!

### No Result → (Add File ↓)(Try Again →) Success!/Fail → Try Again...

### Add File → Set Info → User Info echo'd into template php code → New page simply a copy of the previous PHP page with user submitted info and renamed into different directory

```
<select name="state" id="state" required aria-required="true">
<option value="" disabled>CHOOSE STATE</option>
<option value="AL" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == al) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>ALABAMA</option>
<option value="AK" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ak) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>ALASKA</option>
<option value="AZ" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == az) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>ARIZONA</option>
<option value="AR" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ar) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>ARKANSAS</option>
<option value="CA" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ca) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>CALIFORNIA</option>
<option value="CO" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == co) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>COLORADO</option>
<option value="CT" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ct) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>CONNECTICUT</option>
<option value="DE" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == de) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>DELAWARE</option>
<option value="FL" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == fl) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>FLORIDA</option>
<option value="GA" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ga) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>GEORGIA</option>
<option value="HI" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == hi) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>HAWAII</option>
<option value="ID" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == id) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>IDAHO</option>
<option value="IL" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == il) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>ILLINOIS</option>
<option value="IN" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == in) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>INDIANA</option>
<option value="IA" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ia) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>IOWA</option>
<option value="KS" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ks) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>KANSAS</option>
<option value="KY" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ky) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>KENTUCKY</option>
<option value="LA" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == la) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>LOUISIANA</option>
<option value="ME" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == me) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>MAINE</option>
<option value="MD" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == md) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>MARYLAND</option>
<option value="MA" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ma) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>MASSACHUSETTS</option>
<option value="MI" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == mi) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>MICHIGAN</option>
<option value="MN" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == mn) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>MINNESOTA</option>
<option value="MS" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ms) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>MISSISSIPPI</option>
<option value="MO" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == mo) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>MISSOURI</option>
<option value="MT" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == mt) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>MONTANA</option>
<option value="NE" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ne) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>NEBRASKA</option>
<option value="NV" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == nv) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>NEVADA</option>
<option value="NH" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == nh) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>NEW HAMPSHIRE</option>
<option value="NJ" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == nj) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>NEW JERSEY</option>
<option value="NM" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == nm) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>NEW MEXICO</option>
<option value="NY" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ny) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>NEW YOURK</option>
<option value="NC" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == nc) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>NORTH CAROLINA</option>
<option value="ND" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == nd) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>NORTH DAKOTA</option>
<option value="OH" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == oh) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>OHIO</option>
<option value="OK" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ok) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>OKLAHOMA</option>
<option value="OR" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == 'or') {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>OREGON</option>
<option value="PA" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == pa) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>PENNSYLVANIA</option>
<option value="RI" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ri) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>RHODE ISLAND</option>
<option value="SC" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == sc) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>SOUTH CAROLINA</option>
<option value="SD" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == sd) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>SOUTH DAKOTA</option>
<option value="TN" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == tn) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>TENNESSEE</option>
<option value="TX" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == tx) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>TEXAS</option>
<option value="UT" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == ut) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>UTAH</option>
<option value="VT" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == vt) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>VERMONT</option>
<option value="VA" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == va) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>VIRGINIA</option>
<option value="WA" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == wa) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>WASHINGTON</option>
<option value="WV" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == wv) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>WEST VIRGINIA</option>
<option value="WI" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == wi) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>WISCONSIN</option>
<option value="WY" <?php if($_SESSION['state'] == wy) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?>>WYOMING</option>
</select>
```

Comment: PHP often runs as "nobody" for security reasons so it does not have the right to create new folders outside of the temp folder.  Have PHP write to a file in the temp folder then see who owns that file.  You may need to pre-create the folder where PHP will write files, and give it permission to write there (group writable might work)

Comment: Thank you for responding. Unfortunately that was one of the first things I tried. Appreciate the feedback though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Concept / Flow is clear. You need to check that your Script could create Directory and your Created Directory is Writable. Do check same for File create and Writable. 
First check if the directory is writable. You could get help regarding it here : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109188/how-do-i-check-if-a-directory-is-writeable-in-php`